# Error in SQL UPDATE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this simple SQL query :

```
  UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[EXPLANATIONS] 
  SET [EXPLANATION] = " This is the new explanation." 
  WHERE [RECORDNUMBER] = 123456 
    AND [EXPLANATIONNUMBER] = 7;
```

and I get this error :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name ' This is the new explanation.' .

How can I get rid of this error and update the row correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Use the single quote. Instead of the `"` use `'` So `"This is the new explanation." `  this becomes `'This is the new explanation.'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes are usually used to object names (e.g. column name). That is part of SQL-92 standard.

In ANSI SQL, double quotes quote object names (e.g. tables) which allows them to contain characters not otherwise permitted, or be the same as reserved words (Avoid this, really).

single quotes to the string litral

```
  UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[EXPLANATIONS] 
  SET [EXPLANATION] = 'This is the new explanation.'
  WHERE [RECORDNUMBER] = 123456 AND [EXPLANATIONNUMBER] = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double quotes, use single quotes like:

```
SET [EXPLANATION] = '<i>new explanation</i>'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can update below table using double quotes as well, just add set statement above the query.

```
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  off

UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[EXPLANATIONS] 
  SET [EXPLANATION] = "This is the new explanation."
  WHERE [RECORDNUMBER] = 123456 AND [EXPLANATIONNUMBER] = 7;


set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  on
```